# Visual Studio extension: get language / file type from file name or ProjectItem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing an extension to provide basic project statistics (e.g. lines of code). It's simple enough to iterate a `Solution` tree and find the [`ProjectItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem)s that correspond with files.

The `Document` structure has `Kind` and `Language` properties, but the latter is marked for internal use only, and both require the file to be opened in the editor first.

So... is there a way to:

1. See what files Visual Studio will classify as text files.
2. See what language Visual Studio associates with a given file name / file extension.

without opening the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written such statistics (although only for C# and VB.NET) and both questions are very tricky for all project types / file types / languages. First of all, if you need, you can open an EnvDTE.Document / EnvDTE.TextDocument from an EnvDTE.ProjectItem using the ProjectItem.Open(view) method, which returns an EnvDTE.Window. That doesn't make the window visible, by default is invisible, you would need to call Window.Visible = true to make it visible. When done, you close the (invisible) window with Window.Close, unless it was already opened (you can know calling first ProjectItem.get_IsOpen(view) and later closing or not accordingly).

Now:

- It is very difficult to know if a file is text or not because VS supports many projects, and each project type can consider its files/extensions as text files or not. The best approach that I found is to consider all files as text files unless known extensions that are not text files (.jpg, etc.). Also, notice that not all text files are code files (ex: .txt files). For some features such as a find text feature you may be interested in text files but for an statistics feature you may be interested in code files, not just text files.
- You can know the guid of the language of a file using EnvDTE.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.Language (and EnvDTE.Project.CodeModel.Language). Alas, some project / files have language but do not provide a code model, so you may need to use known extensions to map to a language.

Some useful language guids:

```
     const string LANGUAGE_CSHARP = "{B5E9BD34-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}";
     const string LANGUAGE_IDL = "{B5E9BD35-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}";
     const string LANGUAGE_MANAGED_C = "{B5E9BD36-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}";
     const string LANGUAGE_VBNET = "{B5E9BD33-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}";
     const string LANGUAGE_VISUAL_C = "{B5E9BD32-6D3E-4B5D-925E-8A43B79820B4}";
     const string LANGUAGE_PYTHON = "{888888A0-9F3D-457C-B088-3A5042F75D52}";
     const string LANGUAGE_FSHARP = "{F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786}";
     const string LANGUAGE_R = "{DA7A21FA-8162-4350-AD77-A8D1B671F3ED}";
```

Notice that being VS so extensible, there is no enum for languages. New languages provide new guids.